# Is an EU citizen legally required to hold a passport to resettle in another EU Schengen country?

Tags: eu, schengen, passport

In general, are you legally required to hold a passport to resettle in another EU Schengen country? Or does this depend on each EU country?

For example, if somebody has a Portuguese citizen and they want to relocate to Germany for example, are they legally required to have a passport, or would they only need to have a Portuguese ID?

Comment: Bring your passport, and be on the safe side. Do not know the answer you seek.

Comment: @quantum EU law provides that a national ID card must be accepted.  Someone who has a national ID card definitely does not need a passport.

Answer (score 4):

No, a passport is explicitely not required and a national ID *must* be accepted for all purposes by other EU countries, even those that do not issue national ID cards to their own citizens.

Comment: How do those who are never issued national ID cards avoid taking their passport?

Comment: @quantum Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Country A does not issue national ID cards. Citizen of A wants to go to country B, but does not have an ID card. Is carrying the passport the only option?

Comment: @quantum Yes, more or less. What EU law says is that other EU countries must accept a passport or national ID card. They cannot ask anything else if you have one of those and cannot prefer one over the other. So if you don't have a national ID card, another EU country can legally demand a passport. Note that since Brexit, country A can only be Ireland or Denmark.

Comment: I am sometimes using rather convoluted formulations but it's important to understand that EU law doesn't simply set the rules. It defines a baseline, what must be accepted. Countries are free to be more lenient but not to add arbitrary restrictions. For example, Nordic countries have other arrangements and Danish citizens can go to Sweden without a passport. But Sweden doesn't *have to* accept that under EU law, it just does it based on some earlier agreement and national policy.

Comment: @quantum A passport is also accepted. [Article 8 - Administrative formalities for Union citizens - Freedom of Movement (Directive 2004/38/EC)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02004L0038-20110616#tocId13): 3. *... present **a valid identity card or passport**,...*

Comment: @quantum Ireland (that doesn't issue identity cards to its citizens) would accept a identity card as proof of EU citizenship from those who have one.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm fairly certain that the Irish "passport card" counts as a "national ID" for the purpose of intra-EU travel and relocation (as far as I'm aware that was the primary purpose for which the document was developed).  But I also seem to recall that having an Irish passport is a requirement for getting an Irish passport card.

Comment: @phoog Yes it is. It was intended as a sample of was meant with the 'even those that do not issue national ID cards to their own citizens.' since the UK sample no longer applies. Ireland doesn't require that EU citizens register after 3 months,  only that they have a valid national ID or passport on entry.

Comment: @phoog Yes, indeed, the main difference between the passport card and other national ID card is that you need to have a passport ("passport book") to get it. The card will even have the same expiration date as the passport.